# Run several "long" scripts with remote Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have 3 Powershell scripts: `A.ps1`, `B.ps1`, `RunAB.ps1`.

`A.ps1` and `B.ps1` are on the same machine, `RunAB.ps1` is on a different machine.

I want `RunAB.ps1` to run. via remote powershell, A and B at the same time (i.e, in parallel).

Both A and B take about 2-3 days to finish run.

In order to do this, I wrote `RunAB.ps1` (relevant lines only):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $physical_server_ip -ScriptBlock {Set-Location "C:\Test"; Powershell.exe -File "A.ps1"} -Credential $physical_credential -AsJob

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $physical_server_ip -ScriptBlock {Set-Location "C:\Test"; Powershell.exe -File "B.ps1"} -Credential $physical_credential -AsJob
```

This runs fine at the beginning, but after about 2 hours, the powershell processes of both A and B on remote machine are terminated (they didn't finish)...

If I remove the `AsJob` from second `Invoke-Command` (what causes `RunAB.ps1` to wait at this command) then it seems to fix the issue - A and B keep on running on remote machine, however I don't want `RunAB.ps1` to wait..

What is the correct way of doing what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to extend the Idle Timeouts of the PSSession you are connecting to. The Default is `7200000` which is 2 hours

To see the current timeout values:

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration | Select-Object Name, *Timeout*
```

To set the timeout value:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $physical_server_ip -SessionOption {New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout XXXXXXX} ...
#Where XXXXXX is the value in milliseconds less than the Max timeout.
```

Comment: thanks for answering, there is no `New-SessionOption` did you meant `New-PsSessionOption` ?

Comment: @Noam I did, fixed the typo in my answer.